# How does this relationship map to EDM entities?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm working on a C# WPF app with a MySQL backend using Entity Data Model in VS2010 (.NET 4). I have the following simple test database schema (ignore StudentCourse.Grade for now):

[image]

Students are assigned to courses with a many-to-many relationship via a connecting table. In EDM this is represented as two entities linked by an association mapped to the connecting table:

[image]

So far so good.
Now let's say that each student gets a final grade for each course he/she takes which I've stored in the StudentCourse table as Grade. My problems is somehow getting the grade in the EDM. I've tried creating a new StudentCourse entity mapped to the StudentCourse table but it's set to read-only because it has no id. Adding an id to the table causes Visual Studio to whine because the id field is not mapped in the association(which I don't understand at all).

How is a relationship like this mapped in EDM? I'm open to changing the database schema if need be.

**Edit in reply to Ucodia:**
I don't know. As far as UI goes, grades should be easily accessible for a student or for a course. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: In which entity would you like to see the Grade property? It does not appear on your EDM designer screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Grade to the link table and delete the many-to-many relationship.  Then regenerate the model from the database.  You will find that the StudentCourse table will show in the EDM.  When there are additional fields in the link table, the link table will appear in the model.

Comment: I could, but like I mentioned that then makes it impossible to use StudentCourse to establish an association between Student and Course.

Comment: No, that's not the case.  In the database, you have many-to-one Student to StudentCourse and one-to-many StudentCourse to Course.  That does not change.  The EF model only shows a many-to-many Student-Course relationaship but the plumbing in the background takes account of the StudentCourse table and manages the relationships correctly.  If you add an additional field into the StudentCourse table and rebuild the relationships, the EDM will then show StudentCourse in the model.  Try it!

Comment: Check out this thread and I suggest you read Julie's article.  There are examples of many-to-many relationships in it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030719/entity-framework-4-0-ef-maps-many-to-many-relationships-too-well-in-the-diag/8030796#8030796

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just store the `Grade` on the `Course` entity?

Comment: It is a many to many relationships. Moving Grade means that you will have to duplicate similar Course rows.

Comment: @Ucodia - I don't get what you are saying. It is just saying a `Student` can have many `Courses` right? So why not stash the grade on the course?

Comment: Because you probably have less Course rows than StudentCourse rows. If you move Grade into Course you would uselessly overgrow the Course table. Also as many people attend a Course, it makes no sense that the same Course appears many times in the table.

Comment: Well, I agree on this but that's up to the designer! It seems obvious, but as it is obvious it is probably a design choice.

Comment: If you're implying I store Grade on the Course table and then map that to an entity, it would ruin Course's normalization and make it a major pain to display/edit a distinct list of courses later on. If you mean put Grade in the Course entity without changing the database schema you'll have to come up with a step-by-step guide because I have no idea how to coax the EDM designer to do something like that

Comment: You definitely won't be able to do that from the designer. The EDM designer does not allow custom mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your primary concern is to have something like the Model you designed in EDM designer. If only the object model matters to you, whatever the database looks like, then I would suggest you having a look at EF Code First.

Have a look at this article: [EF Code First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)